# How to speed up for loop execution using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, nlp, python-multiprocessing, spacy

I have two lists. List A contains 500 words. List B contains 10000 words. I am trying to find similar words for List A with respect to B.I am using Spacy's similarity function.

The problem I am facing is that it takes ages to compute. I am new to multiprocessing usage, hence request help.

How do I speed up the execution of the for loop part through multiprocessing in python?

The following is my code.

```
ListA =['Dell', 'GPU',......] #500 words lists
ListB = ['Docker','Ec2'.......] #10000 words lists
s_words = []
for token1 in ListB:
    list_to_sort = [] 
    for token2 in ListA:    
        list_to_sort.append((token1, token2,nlp(str(token1)).similarity(nlp(str(token2)))))
        sorted_list = sorted(list_to_sort, key = itemgetter(2), reverse=True)[0][:2]
        s_words.append(sorted_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package. This I hope will reduce your time significantly. See [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1572) for a sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rishi. Could you be more specific about the sample code. In my case what are the arguments to be passed in map function    
 results = pool.map(test, data)                                                                      Would be really helpful if you can show a working snippet in perspective of my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`nlp.pipe()`](https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe)?

You could do something like this:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
ListA = ['Apples', 'Monkey']  # 500 words lists
ListB = ['Grapefruit', 'Ape', 'Oranges', 'Banana']  # 10000 words lists
s_words = []
docs_a = nlp.pipe(ListA)
docs_b = list(nlp.pipe(ListB))
for token1 in docs_a:
    list_to_sort = []
    for token2 in docs_b:
        list_to_sort.append((token1.text, token2.text, token1.similarity(token2)))
        sorted_list = sorted(list_to_sort, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)[0][:2]
        s_words.append(sorted_list)
print(s_words)
```

That should already speed things up for you. The function `nlp.pipe()` also has the parameter `n_process` which might be what you're looking for.