# How to reduce for loop execution time using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, multiprocessing, spacy

I have two lists. List X contains 1000 words. List Y contains 500 words. I am trying to find similar words for List X with respect to Y.

I am using Spacy's similarity function.

The problem I am facing is that it takes a long time for the for loop part of the execution. I have understood from research that in python, multi threading only gives a illusion of concurrency and hence does not have any real performance increase. Thus I thought multiprocessing is the way but I am new to multiprocessing usage, hence request help.

How do I speed up the execution of the for loop part through multiprocessing in python?

The following is my code.

```
import en_vectors_web_lg
nlp = en_vectors_web_lg.load()
ListX =['HSBC', 'JP Morgan',......] #500 words lists
ListY = ['Currency','Blockchain'.......] #1000 words lists
s_words = []
for token1 in ListY:
    list_to_sort = [] 
    for token2 in ListX:    
        list_to_sort.append((token1, token2,nlp(str(token1)).similarity(nlp(str(token2)))))
        sorted_list = sorted(list_to_sort, key = itemgetter(2), reverse=True)[0][:2]
        s_words.append(sorted_list)
```

Comment: you can reduce computation time by sorting the list outside of the loop.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466369/how-to-speed-up-for-loop-execution-using-multiprocessing-in-python, but I can't flag it as such because no answer was accepted or upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import en_vectors_web_lg


nlp = en_vectors_web_lg.load()


def compare_function(token1, token2, nlp):
    return token1, token2, nlp(str(token1)).similarity(nlp(str(token2)))

from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

tokenlist = [(a,b, nlp) for a, b in itertools.product(ListX, ListY)]


p = Pool(8)

results = p.map(compare_function, tokenlist)
```

If you are under windows, use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = p.map(compare_function, tokenlist)
```